# How to find if the chained asynchronous scripts has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amd

Here's the scenario. I am doing a `$.getScript()`function call to get a script in my javascript file. The script that I'm downloading from the `$.getScript()` tries to download some other scripts that it's dependent on. In my script I'm using `done()` to check if the script loaded completely or not. And if it did, then I try calling the function that's not on the script that I just loaded form `$.getScript` but the script that was loaded in it.

It's getting confusing so let me demonstrate with some code:-

```
//my script.js
$.getScript("http://myexternaljs.com/first.js").done(function(){
    doSecond(); //<- this resides in second.js which is being called in first.js below
}

//first.js
(function(){
    $.getScript("http://firstexternal.com/second.js");
}());

//second.js
function doSecond(){
    return console.log("hello world");
}
```

The problem here is second.js takes a little time to download so I keep getting `doSecond() is undefined` error on my call to `doSecond()` on `done()`.

I could use a timeout and check if `second.js` loaded or not but is there a better way to do this?

I'm open to any `AMD loaders` or `Promises` answers as well.

Comment: Do you have any control over the contents of myexternaljs.com, or is it read-only to you?

Comment: Unfortunately, its read only.

Comment: well if you have power to do it, the best way to do it is to remove `second.js` from `first.js` and have it load inside `first.js`'s `.done` and then put `doSecond()` within a nested `.done` on `second.js`

Comment: Sorry but those two files must exist. I can however make changes to the content of the said files.

Comment: if you don't have power to do that, then no, there's not a better way than to do a `setTimeout` to look for whatever `second.js` loads. Usually in this scenario I put it in a wrapper to try a few times before giving up

Comment: Wait I thought you said they're read-only. And now you *can* modify them? I'm lost.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I can request to make changes to the js file but to me they're read-only, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`$.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, jqXhr, options) {
  // You could be as specific as you need to here.
  if ( options.url.match('second.js') ) {
    doSecond();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could do this inside `ajaxComplete`:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, jqXhr, options) {
  // You could simplify to 
  // doSecond && doSecond()
  // if you can trust that it will always be a function
  if ( doSecond && $.isFunction(doSecond) ) {
    doSecond();
  }
});
```

Comment: major caveat about this is that `.ajaxComplete` **only listens for script includes initiated by jQuery methods.**  It will not pick up on script includes initiated by non-jQuery lib or vanilla js. e.g. using your own `.createElement` or using `document.write`. So if `first.js` is NOT using jQuery to include `second.js`, this will not work

Comment: Based on OP, jQuery is being used. Also, calling `document.write` from a script file that is being loaded asynchronously will remove everything that has already been written to the document.

Comment: re: jQuery. Fair enough; still worth pointing out just in case though. He may have just been giving an example. re: `document.write` rewriting the page: may or may not happen, depending on whether or not the async call was invoked before or after `document.readyState=='complete'`.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. Is there any way to do this without having to know the url of `second.js`?
Here's what I have got in the fiddle so far. http://jsfiddle.net/wsgy6/

Comment: @shriek since `.ajaxComplete` will trigger on every ajax script include anyway, you don't really need to know the url of `second.js` if all you are looking to do is call `doSecond()`. Just do the 2nd example. But you said the url of `second.js` may change.. will the basename change too? any reason why the first example isn't good enough? If you really want to be able to look by full url, it's gotta be exposed in `first.js` somehow, like in a js var you can evaulate

Comment: Aha. I completely overlooked that part. Thank yor for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

**The facts:**

- You have `first.js` and within this script is an include for `second.js`
- You need to make a call to `doSecond()` which is defined in `second.js`
- You need to ensure `doSecond()` is available before you call it
- You can't directly change `first.js` or `second.js` but you can have someone else change it

**Possible solutions, ordered by best to worst**

**1)** Request that `second.js` be removed from `first.js`. Call them separately so that you can nest them:

```
$.getScript("first.js").done(function(){
  $.getScript("second.js").done(function(){
    doSecond(); 
  });
});
```

This is the best solution. There are alternatives to this that basically do he same thing in principle (e.g. other people's answers here). If `first.js` was including `second.js` synchronously or otherwise forcing load before continuing (e.g. option #3 below), you wouldn't be running up against this problem to begin with. Therefore `first.js` already must be structured to deal with `second.js` be **a**sync loaded, so there shouldn't be an issue with them removing it from the file and you calling it yourself.

But you mentioned that the location of second.js is defined in first.js so this somehow isn't feasible to you (why not? can they put the path/to/script in a variable for you to access?)

**2)** Request that `second.js` be wrapped in a `.done` or equivalent loaded callback that pops a callback function that you can define.

```
// inside first.js
$.getScript("second.js").done(function(){
  if (typeof 'secondLoaded'=='function') 
    secondLoaded();      
});


// on-page or elsewhere, you define the callback
function secondLoaded() {
  doSecond();
}
```

This is just a generic and easy "callback" example.  There are a million ways to implement this principle, depending on what all is actually in these scripts and how much effort people are willing to make to restructure things.

**3)** Request that `second.js` script include be changed to be included via `document.write`

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='second.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

This will force js to resolve `document.write` before js can move on, so `second.js` should be loaded by the time you want to use `doSecond()`.  But this is considered *bad practice* because until `document.write` is resolved, nothing else can happen. So if `second.js` is taking forever to load or eventually times out.. that makes for bad UX. So you should avoid this option unless you have no other choice because of "red tape" reasons.

**4)** use `setTimeout` to try and wait for it to load.

```
function secondLoaded() {
  if (!secondLoaded.attempts) secondLoaded.attempts = 0;
  if (secondLoaded.attempts < 5) {
    if (typeof 'doSecond'=='function') {
      doSecond();
    } else {
      secondLoaded.attempts++;
      window.setTimeout('secondLoaded()',100);
    }
  }
}
secondLoaded();
```

I list this worse than #3 but really it's kind of a tossup.. In this situation you basically either have to pick between deciding a cutoff time to just not execute `doSecond()` (in this example, I try 5 times at 100ms intervals), or code it to just keep checking forever and ever (remove the `.attempts` logic or else swap it up w/ `setInterval` and `removeInterval` logic).

Answer (score 1):

You could modify how `$.getScript` works.

```
$.fn.getScript = (function() {
  var originalLoad = $.fn.getScript;
  return function() {
    originalLoad.apply($, arguments);
    $(document).trigger('load_script')
  };
})();
```

This will fire an event every time a script is loaded.

So you can wait for these events to fire and check if your method exists.

```
$(document).one('second_loaded', function() {
  doSecond();
}).on('load_script', function() {
  doSecond && document.trigger('second_loaded');
});
```

Note that `one` rather than `on`. It makes the event fire *once*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when($.getScript("http://myexternaljs.com/first.js"),$.getScript("http://firstexternal.com/second.js"))
.done(function(){
  doSecond();
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but it may have undesired side-effects, because `second.js` will be loaded twice. Also, the actual path to `second.js` may be unknown ahead of time (it is defined in `first.js`).

Comment: @JoeFrambach You're right, `second.js` is being loaded from `first.js` and it could change the naming of that `second.js` anytime it wants to. So, I don't have knowledge of what `second.js` is going to be called ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd facade $.getScript and perform some combination of the above tricks. After reading through the comments it seems that there is a possibility of loading the same script twice.

If you use requirejs this problem is solved for you because it only loads each script once. The answer here is to hang on to the requests made.

### Loader:

```
var requiredScripts = {};

function importScript(url) {
   if (!requiredScripts[url]) {
       requiredScripts[url] = $.getScript(url);
   }

   return requiredScripts[url];
}
```

### Usage:

```
// should cause 2 requests
$.when(
    importScript('first.js'),
    importScript('second.js')
).done(function() {
    // should cause no requests
    $.when(importScript('first.js')).done(function() {});
    $.when(importScript('second.js')).done(function() {});
});
```

**Real world example here using MomentJS and UnderscoreJS**: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Mt5/

Of course requirejs would handle this for you and with better syntax.

### Requirejs

```
define(function(require) {
    var first = require('first'),
        second = require('second');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).one("second", function(e, t) {
  if ( $(this).get(0).hasOwnProperty(e.type) && (typeof second === "function") ) { 
   second(); console.log(e.type, e.timeStamp - t); 
   $(this).off("second") 
  };
   return !second
});


$.getScript("first.js")
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  if ( textStatus === "success" ) {
    first();
    $.getScript("second.js") 
    .done(function( script, textStatus, jqxhr, callbacks ) { 
      var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");
      callbacks.add($(window).trigger("second", [ $.now() ]));         
      return ( textStatus === "success" && !!second 
             ? callbacks.fire()
             : $(":root").animate({top:"0"}, 1000, function() { callbacks.fire() })
             )
    });
  }; 
})
// `first.js` : `function first() { console.log("first complete") }`
// `second.js` : `function second() { console.log("second complete") }`
```